# Python function has access to global variables, and doesn't need passed arguments

Tags: python

When teaching functions in Python I get a little annoyed that the code below actually prints out the greeting. I know the preferred way would be to pass in the name, but, for students, if it works then why do something more complex. I want to teach them how to pass in arguments but if they mess up and forget it will still work. Thoughts about how to approach situations like this without being convoluted or contrived?

```
def greeting():
    print("Hello " + name)


name = input("Enter your name: ")
greeting()
```

Comment: You should teach them about variable scope before giving such examples

Comment: Yep, but that won't make them do it since scope doesn't change the outcome in situations like this.

Comment: If you want to ask questions about how to teach people computer programming, you might have more luck on the [dedicated site for that](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Didn't know that existed. Thanks.

Comment: it works now...  then your students write a real program and this will become a hindenbug.

Comment: You typically would not bother with top level functions and trying to teach scoping... Rather you move into modules and classes where it actually starts to make more sense that you need to import a function or define an instance of a class with a constructor that doesn't have access to the local module's scope

Comment: You should always make clear that there is good and bad coding style. Give at least one examples what could go wrong when using a bad practice. For the case you are giving you could tell them, at the end, to refactor and put the functions into a new module.

Comment: True, but most of their programs won't be very complex since it's an introductory class. So they may not encounter this.

Comment: Alternatively, intentionally rename the variable within the function, and let them figure out (by mistake) that variable names can actually be the same

Comment: It's seems that modules and classes are the way to go.

Comment: Functions that need to recurse are one effective way to demonstrate the inadequacy of abusing globals; they *won't work* without variables which need to be tracked between levels being stored on the stack.

Comment: This question is a fit for our sister site [cseducators.se] Stack Exchange, but is not within StackOverflow's scope.

Answer (score 1):

You can, maybe, try inserting your other function inside a def too. Like:

```
def greeting():
    print("Hello " + name)

def main():
    name = input("Enter your name: ")
main()
greeting()
```

it is roundabout, and visibly wrong, but with this, greeting will not have access to the *name* inside the main() function.

Comment: I was thinking about that and I agree with it being roundabout. I think that having students make another class and then using methods from that class will work and is more legitimate.